# Return specific properties from Firestore object for different users?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, acl

I have the following user object in my Firestore:

```
User {
    email: String
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    preferredName: String
}
```

I have the following requirement:

> If the fetched `user id` is equal to the fetcher's `user id` (the person who's fetching), return all fields, otherwise only return the fetched user's `firstName`, and `lastName`.

This is my current rule in Firebase, which unfortunately blocks access to a user completely:

```
// Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
// document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
// available in rules.
match /users/{userId} {
    allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Security rules allow read access on a document level.

There is no way to use them to filter the data that is returned from the document itself. If you need that, consider creating two collections: one with the public data, and one with the private data.

Comment: That seems like an anti-pattern. Is there a reason you can't do it on a per field basis?

Comment: **What** seems like an anti-pattern?